# css: div takes minimal width and max-height = page height

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have a page where there's no scroll (nor vertical nor horizontal). Body is blue. This body has 2 children:

- Yellow, which has height 100% and 8 children (red ones) and has minimal width as possible, that depends on children amount. Red ones take fixed known height & width.
- White, which has width 100% (takes the rest of the page and located right to it)

Take a look at the snippet bellow. **I want yellow div to have height 100%** and have minimal width that depends only on amount of children .

```css
body  {
  background-color: blue;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

html {
   height: 100%;
} 
.yellow  {
  background-color: yellow;
  height: 100%;
}
.white  {
  background-color: white;
  border: 4px solid green;
  width: 100%;
}
.red  {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 20px;
  margin: 5px;
  width: 35px;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<body>
<div class="yellow">
<i class="red"></i>
<i class="red"></i>
<i class="red"></i>
<i class="red"></i>
<i class="red"></i>
<i class="red"></i>
<i class="red"></i>
<i class="red"></i>
</div>
<div class="white">

</div>
</body>
```

E.g. 6 situations bellow, each one has minimal width and height = 100% of page height.

[image]

e.g. when page height =~ 5 red divs
[image]
e.g. when page height =~ 3 red divs
[image]

I would like to have pure css solution (no js). Flex-box is ok.

Comment: `html{height:100%}` is what you want ?

Comment: Yes, but with height 100% yellow div should take minimal width. I edited the snippet above so yellow div has 4 column (red squares) but can fit into 2. I want it to flex-wrap children.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a non-perfect solution using flexbox. Visually you will have the needed result BUT There is few issues: The white is overflowing and I had to put it in the container of the red elements.

```css
html {
  height: 100%;
  /*simulate height change*/
  animation: change 3s infinite linear alternate;
}

@keyframes change {
  to {
    height: 20%
  }
}

body {
  background-color: blue;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

.yellow {
  background-color: yellow;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-content: flex-start;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  border-right: 4px solid green;
}

.white {
  background-color: white;
  border: 4px solid green;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
}

.red {
  height: 20px;
  margin: 5px;
  width: 35px;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="yellow">
  <i class="red"></i>
  <i class="red"></i>
  <i class="red"></i>
  <i class="red"></i>
  <i class="red"></i>
  <i class="red"></i>
  <i class="red"></i>
  <i class="red"></i>

  <div class="white">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: How do I make overflow to work on white div correcly? It worked when div was was outside of yellow box. Now it's missing vertical scroll, and horizontal scroll is kinda moved from yellow div on "yellow div's width"px.

Comment: @deathangel908 that's the tricky part .. I added width:100% to the white so it will for sure overflow and I added a border to main container for the visual illusion ... Actually this is the only issue, to find what to put instead of width:100%

Comment: @deathangel908 and since it's overflow, you cannot see the vertical scroll bar .. try to reduce width:100% and you will understand

Comment: I can't reduce width, cause in your case it should be `calc(100% - Npx)` where's `N` is width of yellow div which I don't know. Could you please edit your answer after I applied my changes to it?

Comment: @deathangel908 exactly, this is what we are missing here, the N that is not known